# Not able to upload file in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

Whenever user trying to upload a document in SharePoint (2007), he is getting error (error screenshot attached) and not able to do it.

If IIS is reset this is fixed for temporarily but again the issue persists.
Kindly advice on the causes for this issue and solution.

[image: SHAREPOINT UPLOAD ERROR MESSAGE]

Comment: is it happening to a single site or all the sites ? did you checked ULS log, if you are seeing anything useful ?

Comment: this is screenshot of log and don't know it's prevailing in other sites. the

Comment: this is not screenshot of log, try to check in other site...

Comment: sry i didn't attached the screenshot in my last comment.. we are supporting one only one site.. in tat we are having this problem. i will check with other site also.. and this is happening in one server in other server its working fine.. (some months back to balance load another server is introduced ) before that it was working fine.

Comment: ULS log might be the place where you should start... also which server was introduced wfe or application server ?

Comment: it is WebFrontServer. Also Please advice me how to further proceed with the Log.